# How can site A use an xml file on Site B if both are on the same physical server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have 2 sites written in c#; Site A, and Site B. The sites are on the same phyiscal server (IIS7.5, Windows Server 2008R2) with different host header names. On both sites they have identical menus which are built from an XML Datasource. The xml file is www.SiteA.com/menu.xml.

On Site A I read with it be using a relative path ~/menu.xml. This works fine.

On site B I am trying to read it by using a url www.SiteA.com/menu.xml. I am receiving this error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IP Address:Port

I am trying to avoid keeping a copy of the xml file on both sites so that any changes only have to occur on in one place. I think this is a problem that can solved in IIS but I am not really sure. I am reading my xml file in my masterpage.master like this:

```
 <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://www.siteA.com/menu.xml" XPath="Nav/Menu[@type='top']/Module" />
```

Comment: Why not database the menu items?

Comment: The individual who typically makes changes to the site is comfortable with html/css/xml, but not SQL. It was decided to store it in a manner which this individual could more easily update. One of those design choices you don't really like but have to go with.

Comment: Create a GUI admin panel to do it... they don't need to know SQL

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was quite simple and I don't know how I didn't come to it earlier. I simply set up a virtual directory for my shared resources in my second site that pointed to the resource folder in my first site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice which each site can consume and get the shared xml data.